# Redirect a page using htaccess in cakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I am trying to redirect one page in cakephp. My guess is that .htaccess is the way to do this.

I'm trying to redirect from /consultation to /pages/consultation2016

I have this:

```
    Redirect /consultation http://thep.ca/pages/consultation2016
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
   php_value post_max_size 70M
   php_value upload_max_fiesize 70M
    RewriteBase /app
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect without touching .htaccess:

**CakePHP 2** (**[documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing)**):

```
Router::redirect('/consultation','http://thep.ca/pages/consultation2016');
```

**CakePHP 3** **[(documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing)**):

```
$routes->redirect('/consultation','http://thep.ca/pages/consultation2016');
```